# Storing wiki-style revisions in PostgreSQL -- do I need to worry about data size?

Tags: postgresql, compression, wiki

I'm currently getting ready to start work on a very basic data storage application. As part of it, I'd like to store the revisions for large text documents (similar to a Wiki). I am trying to figure out how worried I should be about the size of the data if I store all of the revisions, rather than getting "fancy" and only storing the differences between versions. So for example even if only one word changed in the whole document, I would store the entirety of the document twice with that one word changed.

Obviously that is the easiest way to implement it (and the way that is the least prone to errors in restoring versions based on diffs), but it will also use a fair amount of space.

However, I know that PostgreSQL has automatic compression of data. But even after reading the documentation, I'm not totally sure how that compression works. So I was hoping that some PostgreSQL expert out there might be able to clue me in -- will PostgreSQL be "smart" enough to notice that those two rows have very similar data in the same column and automatically do some compression magic for me? Or is that not really going to help?

Bottom-line, I'd like to go with the simplest solution possible, and if PostgreSQL is going to help me not worry about the space inefficiency that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's "[TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)" compression works on single values, so it won't know or care about other revisions.

You've not said how many documents and how large they are, so it's difficult to be more informative. PostgreSQL itself will happily handle terabytes of data if you've got the machine to support it.

You might want to store the diffs anyway, since that might be what interests you more than entire copies of old versions of the document. In which case, consider using a trigger function to generate them automatically for you. If you can use pl/perl or pl/python it shouldn't be more than a couple of hours work to use a suitable module to generate the diffs for you too.